# How to select rows with a certain value in r?

Tags: r, sorting, filtering, sublist

I am trying to edit my dataframe but cannot seem to find the function that I need to sort this out.
I have a dataframe that looks roughly like this:

```
Title                  Description       Rating
Beauty and the Beast   a                 2.5
Aladdin                b                 3
Coco                   c                 2
```

etc.
(rating is between 1 and 3)

I am trying to edit my dataframe so that I get a new dataframe where there is no decimal numbers for the rating column.
i.e: the new dataframe would be:

```
Title                  Description       Rating
Aladdin                b                 3
Coco                   c                 2
```

As Beaty and the Beast's rating is not 1, 2 or 3.

I feel like there's a simple function in R that I just cannot find on Google, and I was hoping someone could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `subset` (from `base R`) with a comparison on the integer converted values of 'Rating'

```
subset(df1, Rating == as.integer(Rating))
#    Title Description Rating
#2 Aladdin           b      3
#3    Coco           c      2
```

---

Or if we are comparing with specific set of values, use `%in%`

```
subset(df1, Rating %in% 1:3)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Title = c("Beauty and the Beast", "Aladdin", "Coco"
), Description = c("a", "b", "c"), Rating = c(2.5, 3, 2)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the remainder after dividing by 1 and select rows where the remainder is 0.

```
subset(df, Rating %% 1 == 0)

#    Title Description Rating
#2 Aladdin           b      3
#3    Coco           c      2
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use the dplyr function in R

```
  library(dplyr)

  df1 %>%
    filter(R != 2.5)
```